# Как статически скомпилировать NativeAPI.dll в качестве обертки над другой библиотекой без исходного кода этой библиотеки?

Tags: c++, dll, 1с

Я не настоящий сварщик...
Имеется задача написать NativeAPI.dll обертку для использования сторонней библиотеки в 1С.
Интересует принципиальная возможность этого дела и куда копать?
Предполагается, что внешняя библиотека будет статически включена в нашу библиотеку обёртку.
И, похоже, исходных кодов библиотеки нет. Есть только описание её API.

Comment: чтобы что-то скомпилировать статически нужны исходники и вообще, лучше будет найти настоящего сварщика

Comment: Собтсвенно, а зачем ? в чем проблема указывать путь к библиотеке ?

Comment: @user78606670 Хочется самому стать настоящим сварщиком :-)

Comment: @Evgenii Izhboldin Есть какой-нибудь пример, как это вообще выглядит?
Как я это вижу сейчас. Допустим, в контрукторе объекта в 1С я передаю путь к сторонней библиотеке в свою обёртку, а обёртка будет использовать этот путь при проксировании методов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался в вопросе.

Во-первых, в моём вопросе есть путаница в терминологии. По факту статическое включение библиотеки мне не нужно было. Достаточно было явно или неявно динамически слинковать нужную мне библиотеку.

Один из подводных камней, с которым я столкнулся:

- При подключении nativeAPI.dll к 1С, 1С, похоже, копирует бинарник библиотеки куда-то себе, возможно во временные файлы. Поэтому возникают проблемы с обращением к слинкованной внешней библиотеке. Чтобы решить эту проблему, каталог с внешней библиотекой можно добавить в переменные среды, например.